# Spring 5 controller return html string to load in Browser

Tags: java, html, spring, rest, spring-mvc

The old code that I had was a Java Servlet which took in some parameters and pushed out an HTML string:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // Delegate the action
    doAction(request, response);
}
```

The 'doAction' method did something like this:

```
public void doAction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // Read the template EHR HTML file
    String html = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/viewer.html")), "utf-8");
     ... make some changes to html ...
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(html);   
}
```

And this sent an HTML string to the browser and all the relative locations worked.  I mean we have a directory structure where we have:

```
webapp/viewer.html
webapp/js
webapp/css
webapp/img
```

An this page loads, and all the loaded js and css and img files all worked great.  I should say the call to this is like:
http://localhost:8080/webapp/servlet?{some parameters)

Now, we are using Spring 5 and I have lots of experience setting up Spring and creating RESTful end-points that spit out JSON.   I call a new Spring Controller passing in variables, and the back-end logic all works.   Now I want to output HTML the same way the old servlet worked.   This is what I have now.

```
@Controller
public class ViewerController
{
    @GetMapping(value = "/viewer", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String getPatientViewerData(
@RequestParam(value = "token", required = true) String token, 
@RequestParam(value = "myid", required = true) String myid)
{
    String html = "";
    try {
        html = service.getHtmlFromBusinessLogic();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return html;
}
```

When I test this, I DO get HTML returned to my String, but all the relative links are thrown off, so if I my call to this controller is:
http://localhost:8080/webapp/api/controller?{some parameters)
Then all my relative links are looking for:
http://localhost:8080/webapp/api/js/somejs.js  or
http://localhost:8080/webapp/api/css/somecss.css

The Application Initializer in this Spring 5 webapp is as follows:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ApplicationInitializer.class);

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]
    { ViewerAppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]
    {};
}

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
       return new String[] { "/api/*" };
    }

}
```

So, I am sure the easiest solution would be to remove the "/api/ for any rest calls here.  I was hoping there would be another solution, but I am not sure if there is any.

Any help would be great.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're code looks ok. Maybe the only thing you need to define is how to serve ***static resources*** in your *Spring config*. Something like this:

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebMvc 
> public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer { 
>     @Override 
>     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
>         registry.addResourceHandler("/**") // your prefered mapping, for example web app root
>                 .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); // project files location
>     }
> }
> ```

This way you tell *Spring* where to *expose* all your `css, js, etc...` also you don't need to change your ***DispatcherServlet*** url mapping.